# Magento - change customer group on successful order

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using paypal as the gateway and I thought I would edit the IPN listener and update the customer group from there depending on paypal result.

Is there a more 'Magento' way of doing this, like overriding methods, and if so where would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Event observer would make sense here. Not sure if `paypal_payment_transaction_save_after` event would work here; checking order after save for successful IPN payment would work.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for this functionality, this is what I did:

To override the Magento 1.7.0.2 paypal routines I copied

/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/

to

/app/code/local/Mage/Paypal/

I then added the following method to /app/code/local/Mage/Paypal/Model/Ipn.php

```
protected function _changeUserGroup($group){

    $invoice_id = $this->_request['invoice'];

    // get the resource model
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

    // retrieve the read connection
    $read = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

    // get the customer_id for the invoice from the database
    $customer_id = (int) $read->fetchOne($read->select()->from('sales_flat_order','customer_id')->where("increment_id='$invoice_id'")->limit(1));

    // retrieve the write connection
    $write = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

    // raw query
    $query = "UPDATE customer_entity SET group_id = $group WHERE entity_id = $customer_id";

    // execute the query
    $write->query($query);

}
```

You can then call this method at whatever point you want in the IPN procedure to suit your purpose. I found http://fishpig.co.uk/blog/direct-sql-queries-magento.html useful for the database calls.